# What are the procedures to consider when migrating from Tomcat to Glassfish webserver?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, glassfish

I am building a webapplication project that runs on Tomcat web server. Now I think we will be using Glassfish server in my build webapp. Do I only need to replace the servlet.api of my jsp project to a servlet.api of a Glassfish server?

Comment: Apache is a big software company with many many products such as HTTPD and Tomcat. Please do not say "Apache" while you really meant "Tomcat". You also don't say "Sun" or "Oracle" when you say "Java", "JSP", "Servlet" or "Glassfish".

Answer (score 0):

You should in first place not have a servlet API JAR file in your webapp project at all. Get rid of **all** container-specific JAR files in your webapp project. This way your webapp is fully portable across all containers, exactly as intented by Java EE specification.

Having container-specific libraries in the webapp project is a quite common starter's mistake in a careless attempt to "fix" compilation errors on `javax.servlet.*` classes they face in their Eclipse/Netbeans IDE. This should in first place have been solved differently.

#### See also:

- [How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project/4076706#4076706)

Comment: But Im almost done with my project. In very start I already place my servlet.api in my libraries that come in apache tomcat...What are the procedure I need to make when changing my webserver to glassfish?

Comment: I'm not sure how that's a hard task. Just delete all copies of Tomcat-specific JARs in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder. They do not belong there. Do you understand the cause and the solution in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Before migrating your project from Tomcat to Glassfish, it is very important to create **web.xml** in Configuration Files folder. So, create new Servlet in main package. Netbeans(in my case) can generate web.xml Configuration Files folder. Then copy all files from Tomcat server project to Glassfish server project. Then, write all servlet information in **web.xml**.

If you cannot follow this step, they Definitely, you can face the problem like **404 Page not found error** once you executed your final Web application.

Best of Luck !!!!!